# Overlapping divs and spacer

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, z-index

[image: divs]

Hi! I'm having this situation infront of me, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

[image: divs2]

My code looks like this:

```
        <div class="about-me">
            <div class="aboutme-icon-holder">
                <img class="aboutme-icon" src="aboutme-icon.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="aboutme-link-holder">
                <a class="aboutme-link" href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my css:

```
.spacer{
float:left;
display: flex;
content:"";
width:300px;
height:5px;
color: white;
margin: auto;
z-index: 2;
}
```

My backgroud css code looks like this:

```
.about-me{
float: left;
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin-right: 32px;
background: #1cb459;
background-image: url("aboutme-aboutme-overlay.png");
display: block;
position: relative;;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Although I can see it with inspect tool I can't get my spacer on top of the background (and background image). I have look through plenty of sites but the most hard thing for me is putting it in words together. Thanks for help

Comment: Can you show an image what the wanted result is?

Comment: First image is what I'm having (the spacer is behind background) and I want to drag it to the top position to be like splicing my green box in half :)

Second image is result (with white spacer on top)

Comment: try to change `color: white;` to `background: white` in .spacer class

Comment: I don't really believe it, but it worked xD hahaha I was searching some complicated solution for like a 45 min now hahaha Thank you a lot Artem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
.spacer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: white;
    content: "";
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    height: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Artem was 2 mins faster, but thank you aswell! That's the correct answer :)